# ORA-06530: Reference to uninitialized composite

Tags: oracle, plsql

When I am executing the package I get an error message:

> error in the emp_test ORA-06530: Reference to uninitialized composite

Can u explain how I can initialized an object type in a package?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE emp_obj AS OBJECT
(
  emp_no   number,
  salary   number,
  job   varchar2(20)
);
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY emp_dummy_pk IS
  PROCEDURE emp_test IS
    CURSOR emp_cur IS
      SELECT empno, sal, job FROM emp;

    l_emp_no  emp_obj;
  BEGIN
    FOR emp_rec IN emp_cur LOOP
      l_emp_no.emp_no := emp_rec.empno;
      l_emp_no.salary := emp_rec.sal;
      l_emp_no.job := emp_rec.job;

      BEGIN
        emp_pk.emp_chk( p_emp_no => l_emp_no );
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
          dbms_output.put_line( 'error in the emp_pk.emp_no ' || SQLERRM );
      END;
    END LOOP;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      dbms_output.put_line( 'error in the emp_test ' || SQLERRM );
  END;
END;
```

```
BEGIN
  emp_dummy_pk.emp_test;
END;
```

Comment: You do know that you are using `[oracle]`, not `[mysql]` (your initial tag)?

Answer (score 7):

You can initialize it using the constructor:

```
l_emp_no := NEW emp_obj( emp_rec.empno, emp_rec.sal, emp_rec.job );
```