# Reference to uninitialized composite error in PL/SQL procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm a beginner in Oracle DB. I've created this object type:

```
create or replace 
TYPE behzadtype AS OBJECT 
( /* TODO enter attribute and method declarations here */ 
  SESSIONID Number,
  myID Number
)
```

And this stored procedure:

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE PROCEDURE2(temp in behzadtype) AS 
BEGIN
  insert into beh values(temp.myID,'behiheib');
END PROCEDURE2;
```

I execute this stored procedure in run PL/SQL windows:

```
DECLARE
  TEMP SYSTEM.BEHZADTYPE;
BEGIN
  -- Modify the code to initialize the variable
  TEMP.myID := 9;

  PROCEDURE2(
    TEMP => TEMP
  );
END;
```

But I then get the following error message:

```
Connecting to the database behi.
ORA-06530: Reference to uninitialized composite
ORA-06512: at line 5
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database behi.
```

What happened? Why do I get that error?

Comment: I guess you need to initialize your object: `TEMP := BEHZADTYPE()` before assigning values to its members.

Comment: @mustaccio thanks man,how can i write that code in my procedure?

Comment: As an aside, it looks like you're creating objects in the system schema. Don't do this, as it's a "special" schema and you will probably see odd effects as a result; instead, you should create a separate schema with the appropriate privileges and create your objects there.

Comment: @behzad I gave you a solution in one of your questions earlier today!

Comment: possible duplicate of [ORA-06530: Reference to uninitialized composite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633276/ora-06530-reference-to-uninitialized-composite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to [`instantiate`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/10_objs.htm#1972) it .. And the exception you get now is similar to `NullPointerException` in `Java`.

So do it in `DECLARE`

```
DECLARE
    TEMP BEHZADTYPE := BEHZADTYPE(null,null) ;
```

Or

```
DECLARE
  TEMP BEHZADTYPE ;
BEGIN
  -- Modify the code to initialize the variable
TEMP := BEHZADTYPE(null,null) ;
  PROCEDURE2(
    TEMP => TEMP
  );
END;
```

Comment: thanks my friend,i'm write your code but i get this error:Error(5,8): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEHZADTYPE" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ; The symbol "." was substituted for "BEHZADTYPE" to continue.

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi , you have to do this declare